# Где cкачать Delphi?

Tags: delphi

Где скачать нормальный, небракованный делфи? Скачал недавно, а там только для создания модулей.

Comment: На офсайте не пробовали?)

Comment: Я не могу его найти.

Comment: шо-таки вам не понравилось в этой ссылке?

Comment: Вот нафига ссылки ворованный софт ставить? 

Я даже не удаляю, пусть админы думают.

Comment: Ну люди все равно будут искать крякнутую версию по этому лучше сразу дать нормальную ссыль

Comment: Пусть ищут ненормальные. Мож вирей нахватают да хард спалят.

Comment: аа окче. а ты думаешь, что ты кинешь ему ссылку на офф сайт и он сразу купит себе делфи? или скачает бесплатный обрубок?

Comment: Ну можно скачать с оф сайта, а все равно кряк будут искать, на оф сайте он платный просто :)

Comment: я сам работал на делфях, на которые дал ссылку. если бы не знал что-как, то не стал бы линк выкладывать

Comment: Мне все равно, откровенно говоря)

 1. Из-за этой ссылки могут быть проблемы у хэшкода

 2. Я как идеологический противник воровства(любого) ставлю админов в известность. Через часик сам удалю, если не появятся.

 3. Если миллионы людей воспитаны на кражах и не понимают, что плохого в том, чтобы урезать ЗП человеку, благодаря которому ты получаешь свою зп - это все равно не значит, что это правильно.

Comment: я тебя понимаю. но согласись, что прежде, чем покупать столь дорогой софт, его надо испытать в полном объеме и посмотреть на все его функциональные особенности. лицензионная пробная версия не дает этого. следовательно разумным вариантом является тестирование пиратки. ДА - она может быть багнутая и кривая, и такую я бы точно не стал юзать. Но в моем случае, прежде, чем мне на рабочее место приобрели Delphi XE2 я его тестил эту пиратскую среду домашних условиях.

ЗЫ. лицуха, кстати, тоже изобилует багами, ошибками и тд...

Comment: Так вы зайдите в магазин и покусайте там весь ассортимент колбасы, чтоб определиться, что вам нравится. Охрана доступнее объяснит. Или там не знаю, кольцо из ювелирки потаскать возьмите, или на мерсе покатайтесь, там еще быстрее и доступнее будет, правда, возможен и летальный исход.

Какая нафиг разница, с какой целью совершена кража? По софту уйма обзоров, если вам обязательно надо потыкать пальцем - триалки хватит.

Вообще подумываю о том, чтобы вместо блокировки запиливать в софт системные вызовы, палящие железо. А потом читать форумы и веселиться)

Comment: @teano, Эмбаркадеро и так дает вам 30 дней на "испытать" на каждую зареганную учетку. Неужели этого мало?

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что этот вопрос не относится ни к программированию, ни к администрированию

Answer (score 4):

[Embarcadero® Delphi® XE2](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi): платная и пробная версии.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще качать не рекомендую. Его нужно покупать. Если не покупать - будут проблемы начиная от отсутствия тех. поддержки и кончая тем, что правоохранительные органы могут обнаружить это правонарушение и как минимум оштрафовать. Ну, и не ясен статус программ, которые созданы с помощью пиратской версии среды.

Если же совсем уж хочется (или очень нужно, а денег нет), то есть сайты торрентов по сами_знаете_каким адресам. Гугль в помощь. Последняя выложенная там версия Delphi XE3. Надо сказать, вполне себе полнофункциональная. Главное - читайте внимательно комментарии других пользователей и проверяйтесь антивирусом. Мало ли доступный для скачивания файл будет заражен троянским конем.

Сам же я стараюсь сейчас пользоваться свободными средствами. Например, компилятором gcc (к которому есть ["компилятор" Pascal](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Pascal)) и [библиотекой Qt](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt). А для паскаля есть - [fpc](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_Pascal) и среда [Lazarus](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazarus).